# What kind of datatype is this, and how do I use it in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, json

My CMS adds the data from a 'multiple' selectbox to my mysql db in the following format:

```
["blabla","blabla2","blabla3","blabla4"]
```

it looks kind of JSONy, so it's probably just that, but how can I use it in a query, for example if I want to select all rows with blabla3 in that column. Can I use `IN`, or `FIND_IN_SET` ? They probably chose this format for a reason, at least that's what I thought :D

Thanks guys, Id love to add a more appropriate title, but I couldn't think of one.

Comment: Definitely is a valid JSON array.

Comment: What does the column datatype say it is?

Comment: Yes, there are set of functions created by someone. which you can import using `.sql` script and you can use to do some stuff with json in MySQL. I forgot the name. Give me some time

Comment: Check this, http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2013/mysql-5-7-sql-functions-for-json-udf/

Comment: @Flosculus it's varchar(255).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array. You can use `IN` to find all the matches:

```
$in = "(" . implode(', ', array_map($blahs, function($b) use ($conn) {
    return "'" . $conn->escape($b);
})) . ")";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE blahCol IN $in";
```